# How do I change textview color in listview as per data

Tags: android

I get parking slot number and its respective status of particular area from sql database and populate list view in onpostexecute method of async class. Now i need to change the color af text view as green if status is 0,as red if status is 1, as orange is status is 1.

I used hashmap to store slot number and status in jet value pair. I tried to get data from textview and change as per it but it shows null as listview and listview item are in different layout.

My code to get data and populate list view

```
     public class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    public Context context;

    public GetHttpResponse(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String SetServerString = "";
        Log.d("json",FinalJSonObject);
        try {
            if (FinalJSonObject != null) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;


                try {

                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);

                    JSONObject jsonObject;

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing Student Name, Phone Number, Class into Variables.
                        sno = jsonObject.getString("slot_number").toString();
                        status = jsonObject.getString("reserv_status").toString();


                        HashMap<String, String> slot = new HashMap<>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        slot.put("sno", sno);
                        slot.put("status", status);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        slotList.add(slot);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SetServerString ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     Log.d("bhjg",result);
        // Setting Student Name, Phone Number, Class into TextView after done all process .
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ShowSingleRecordActivity.this, slotList,
                R.layout.slotlist_item, new String[]{"sno","status"}, new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2
        });

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
      /*  TextView v1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView vh=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String v=vh.getText().toString();
        if (slot.get("status").equals("0"))
        {
         v1   .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        }
       else if (v.equals("1"))
        {
            v1   .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
        else if (v.equals("2"))
        {
            v1   .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
        }*/
    }
}
```

I expect the list view with textview in respective colour differentiation

Comment: first for that use-case, you need to use Custom List view Adapter,(plenty tutorials available on Internet), secondly use recycled view which is more flexible than list view.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleAdaper adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ShowSingleRecordActivity.this, slotList,
                R.layout.slotlist_item, new String[]{"sno","status"}, new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2
        });

change list adapter as simple adapter